# DSolve Doesn't Return a Solution or Error

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

DSolve is not returning anything other than the original expression on

```
DSolve[{z''[s] + 
    2/(R^2 - z[s]^2 - y[s]^2) (z[s]*z'[s]^2 + 2*y[s]*y'[s] z'[s] - 
       z[s] y'[s]^2) == 0, 
  y''[s] + 2/(R^2 - z[s]^2 - y[s]^2)*(y[s]*y'[s]^2 + 
       2*z[s]*z'[s]*y'[s] - y[s]*z'[s]^2) == 0}, {z[s], y[s]}, s]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this differential equation too difficult?

Comment: When _Mathematica_ returns `DSolve` or `Integrate` unevaluated, then it _is_ too difficult. You may try this: assign a number to `R`, specify initial conditions, and apply `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict (z[s]^2 + y[s]^2) <= R^2 in an effort to make it easier?

Comment: You could try the `Assumptions` options, e.g. `Assumptions -> R^2 > z[s]^2 + y[s]^2`. But that won't help.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

We can change `{z, y}` to polar coordinates `{r, t}` and reduce the order of the `t` differential equation of the resulting system.  After that, `DSolve` can handle it.

```
ClearAll[z, y, r, t, u, s];
syszy = {                    (* OP system *)
   z''[s] + 2/(R^2 - z[s]^2 - y[s]^2) (z[s]*z'[s]^2 + 2*y[s]*y'[s] z'[s] - 
        z[s] y'[s]^2) == 0, 
   y''[s] + 2/(R^2 - z[s]^2 - y[s]^2)*(y[s]*y'[s]^2 + 2*z[s]*z'[s]*y'[s] - 
        y[s]*z'[s]^2) == 0};
sysrt = syszy /. {           (* to polar coordinates *)
     z -> Function[s, r[s] Cos[t[s]]], 
     y -> Function[s, r[s] Sin[t[s]]]} // Simplify;
sysrt = Equal @@@            (* put in form  r''[s] ==.., t''[s] ==.. *)
     First@Solve[sysrt, {r''[s], t''[s]}];
sysru = sysrt /. t -> Derivative[-1][u] (* reduce order *)
```

[image]

There are eight solutions returned for the reduced system `sysru`.  Like a miracle, the solution for `u` can be integrated to give `t` in all eight.

```
dsolru = DSolve[sysru, {r, u}, s];  (* solve reduced system *)

kk = 1;                             (* Length@dsolru == 8 sols *)
dsolrt = {dsolru[[kk, 1]],          (* k-th sol, r, t -> Integrate[u] *)
   t -> Function @@ {s, Integrate[u[s] /. dsolru[[kk]], s] + C[4]}};
dsolzy = Thread[{z, y} ->           (* polar to  {z, y} solution *) 
   (Function[s, #] & /@ 
     Simplify[{r[s] Cos[t[s]], r[s] Sin[t[s]]} /. dsolrt])]
```

[image]

I spot checked it and the other seven solutions (`kk = 2..8`) with the following:

```
syszy /. Equal -> Subtract /. dsolzy /. {R -> 4} /. {C[1] -> 1/2, 
   C[2] -> 1/3, C[3] -> 1/4, C[4] -> 1} /. s -> 1.`24
(*  {0.*10^-17 + 0.*10^-17 I, 0.*10^-17 + 0.*10^-17 I}  *)
```

I tried checking it also with the following, but it didn't finish within ten minutes:

```
syszy /. dsolzy // 
  Quiet@Simplify[#, TimeConstraint -> 0.1] & // AbsoluteTiming
```

Further numerical verification:

```
syszy /. Equal -> Subtract /. dsolzy /. {R -> 4} /. {C[1] -> 1/2, 
     C[2] -> 1/3, C[3] -> 1/4, C[4] -> 1} /. 
   s -> RandomReal[{-1, 2}, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 32] // Abs // Max
(*  0.*10^-18  *)
```